# Segue not working with custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell that I am using in my table view that loads a list of categories, and when selecting an item it should bring you to the next view that lists the products in that category.

The issue is that I've created this cell in its own xib file and made a custom class, and when I try to hook up the prototype cell in the main storyboard to a segue, it doesn't work.

If I call the segue in didSelectCellForRowAtIndexPath it only performs the segue when you select another cell other than the first one you tap. But loads the info from the first cell tapped and not the second.

Here is some of the code for the view controller.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *qrTableIdentifier = @"QRTableCell";

    QRTableCell *cell = (QRTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:qrTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QRTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    QRDoc *category = self.qrload.categories[[indexPath row]];

    cell.nameLabel.text = category.data.category;
    cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(category.data.color)];
    cell.bulletImage.image = category.bullet;
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Preparing for seque");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showCategorySegue"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //QRDoc *category = self.qrload.categories[[sender row]];
        QRDoc *category = self.qrload.categories[[indexPath row]];
        NSLog(@"Loading in new category");
        QRCatViewController *catVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        catVC.selectedCategory = category.data.category;
        catVC.categoryColor = category.data.color;
    }
}
```

And for the tableview cell, which is where I think the issue may lie.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

The cell itself only consists of an imageview and label right now, so I don't see what the issue could be with it. Would I need to create the cell programmatically for this to work correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't call the segue in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I may have not, but I just put in the code for it and it still won't work. I think it may have to do with the identifiers for the cells. Would you have any idea about that? I've gotten it to work with a segue but then the cell ends up blank.

Comment: I don't think so. Paste what you've tried to do int `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, since we don't know when you call the to `performSegue`.

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCategorySegue" sender:self];

Comment: I've put a log statement in there as well and it looks like the function is never getting called anyways so I am going to try to look into the reasons for that

Comment: I've just figured it out actually, thanks for pointing me towards that function as the issue. After the void I hadn't typed in tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

Answer (score 0):

*In all likelihood, this was just a typo.*

In such situations, I propose starting on a clean slate, and compare *working code* against *failing one*.

[image]

I have enclosed compact project solving the custom cell with a `Storyboard`, which offers an alternative to separate `XIB`.

Referencing a `UITableViewCell` from separate `XIB` merely requires a single line of code:

```
tableView.register(
    UINib(nibName: "XIBSectionHeader", bundle:nil),
    forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-19778484) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-19778484).